# How are 1-ups awarded in Donkey Kong's Crash Course?

Tags: nintendo-land

What are the conditions for earning a 1-up in the Donkey Kong's Crash Course minigame in Nintendo Land?

[image: Earning a 1-up in Donkey Kong's Crash Course]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Donkey_Kong%27s_Crash_Course):

> The player is awarded an extra life every 2000 points

That seems correct, looking at the score in your screenshot.